Firebase Cloud Messaging: FCM Token Stops Working After Some Time in React App with Vite
I'm working on a React application using Vite, and I've implemented push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). Initially, everything works fine—the device receives notifications as expected. However, after some time, the notifications stop working, and I receive an error when sending messages from the server stating that the device doesn't exist.
Here are the details:

The FCM token remains the same over time; I always get the same token when requesting it in Notification.jsx.
If I delete all data in the user's browser (clearing cache, storage, etc.) and reset the notification permissions, then allow notifications again, I receive a new token, and notifications start working again.
After a while, the issue repeats: notifications stop working, and I have to clear the browser data again to fix it temporarily.

I suspect that the FCM token is expiring or becoming invalid, but I'm not sure how to handle this properly. Below is my code:
Notification.jsx:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { messaging } from "../firebase";
import { getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";
import api from "../axiosInstance";
import { saveFcmToken } from "../utils/storage";

function Notification() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestPermission = async () => {
      try {
        // Wait for the service worker registration
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
        
        // Request the token
        const token = await getToken(messaging, {
          vapidKey: 'YOUR_VAPID_KEY',
          serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
        });

        if (token) {
          console.log("Token generated: ", token);
          
          // Save token to local storage
          saveFcmToken(token);

          // Send token to the backend
          await api.post("/save-token", {
            fcmToken: token
          });
          console.log("Token saved to database successfully:", token);
        } else {
          console.log("No registration token available.");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error getting token: ", err);
      }
    };

    // Handle incoming messages while the app is in the foreground
    const unsubscribe = onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      console.log("Message received.", payload);
    });

    requestPermission();

    // Clean up subscription on unmount
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return null;
}

export default Notification;

firebase-messaging-sw.js:
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Firebase configuration
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "your-app.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "your-app",
  storageBucket: "your-app.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
  measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("Received background message", payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: 'your-icon.png', 
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

Additional Information:

Environment:

React with Vite
Firebase SDK v9 in the main app (Notification.jsx)
Firebase SDK v8 in the service worker (firebase-messaging-sw.js)


Issue Details:

The FCM token doesn't seem to refresh automatically.
After some time, the server reports that the device associated with the token doesn't exist.
Manually clearing browser data and resetting permissions generates a new token and temporarily fixes the issue.



What I've Tried:

Regenerating the FCM token by clearing browser data and resetting notification permissions (works temporarily).
Ensuring that the service worker is registered correctly.
Confirming that the VAPID key and Firebase configuration are correct.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
